# should i expose repository to controller when using service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I currently developing asp mvc using unit of work, generic repository and service patterns. I get a little confused on how the design should work in the controller. 
Should i expose the repository to the controller? or should the controller know only the service? 
The controller need repository to retrieve entities for the combobox list. 
The problem to exposing repository is that it has save and delete method and should only be called by the service. 
can someone help me on this problem?

Comment: [Can I access a repository from presentation layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394967/can-i-access-a-repository-from-presentation-layer)

Comment: If you have a service layer then why do you even want to expose repository to controller. You should rather add another method to retrieve data for the combolist.

Answer (score 4):

The repository pattern is used to abstract away the data source.

There is no need to abstract away the abstraction. So I would use the repository.

However, as soon as you start to get business logic inside the presentation layer you should extract that and put it in a service.

Comment: @Reynaldi: Are you happy with the answer?

Comment: @Reynaldi: Can you accept the answer, or do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirement for any business logic in front of the persistence layer (Repository).  The moment you have any, it will end up in the Controller.  This might be acceptable for a very simple system, but the moment you expand (REST APIs, Admin/Support app, Offline/Batch Processing) the system beyond the toy state, you will want to push that logic to a shared tier, indeed, the Service layer.  Just put in the abstraction now, and save yourself some refactoring later.  This also keeps the Controllers in the business they were meant to be in, directing traffic and calling services to get/put data.

Comment: Presentation layer should only reference the service layer and not the repository layer. As in your case, sometimes however we need to create a "Pass through" through service layer, just to expose it to the presentation layer.